# Dot product vs Element-wise multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vector

What is the different between the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) "$\cdot$" and the [element-wise multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) notation $\odot$ in [Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistics)? I referred to [Hamilton's Time-Series Analysis](https://www.amazon.ca/Time-Analysis-James-Douglas-Hamilton/dp/0691042896), and these seem to have the same definition. For instance, for two $n\times 1$ [vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, is
\begin{equation}
 \vec{a}\odot \vec{b}\overset{?}{\equiv} \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_ib_i
\end{equation}

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The difference operationally is the [aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) by [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). With the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), you [multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication) the corresponding components and add those products together. With the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (element-wise product) you multiply the corresponding components, but do not aggregate by summation, leaving a new [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)) with the same dimension as the original operand vectors. And on that point, the dot product of two vectors gives a scalar number while the Hadamard product of two vectors gives a vector.

$$c = \vec{x}^T \cdot \vec{y} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}^T \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
           y_{1} \\
           y_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           y_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} =
    [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n] \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
           y_{1} \\
           y_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           y_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\vec{z} = \vec{x} \odot \vec{y} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} \odot \begin{bmatrix}
           y_{1} \\
           y_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           y_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
           x_1y_{1} \\
           x_2y_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_ny_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

Note that $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ must have the same [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)). The Hadamard product is often defined in terms of [matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) in many sources, but for general [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) it suffices that they have the same shape. For two vectors, this is tantamount to having the same dimension.

So in general $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} \neq \vec{x} \odot \vec{y}$.

Furthermore, [$\|\vec{x} \odot \vec{y}\| \leq \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207251/proof-that-vecx-odot-vecy-leq-vecx-vecy) and [$\|\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}\| \leq \|\vec{x}\| \|\vec{y}\|$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). But since $Pr\left( \|\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}\| \leq \|\vec{x} \odot \vec{y}\| \right) \approx .67$ for some choice of probability space (see link on $\|\vec{x} \odot \vec{y}\| \leq \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|$), there isn't a direct inequality between their norms.

> Footnote: The dot product is also an example of an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) while the Hadamard product is not. This is important for certain forms of [rotational invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_invariance), but that is not really a 'statistics' SE point.

Answer (score 0):

Element-wise(Hadamard) multiplication(product) doesn't need summation after multiplication while dot multiplication(product) needs.

#### <Element-wise(Hadamard) multiplication (product)>

For example, element-wise multiplication doesn't need summation after multiplication so the result is `[12, 21, 20]` as shown below.

- Element-wise multiplication is the multiplication of 0D or more D tensors(arrays).
- The rule which you must follow to do element-wise multiplication is 2 tensors(arrays) must have the same number of rows and columns.

```
[a, b, c] x [d, e, f] = [ad, be, cf]
1 row       1 row 
3 columns   3 columns

[2, 7, 4] x [6, 3, 5] = [12, 21, 20]
                       [2x6, 7x3, 4x5]
 [2, 7, 4]
  x  x  x 
 [6, 3, 5]
     ||
[12, 21, 20]
```

In [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) with `*` or [mul()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mul.html). *`*` or `mul()` can multiply 0D or more D tensors(arrays) by element-wise multiplication:

```py
import torch

tensor1 = torch.tensor([2, 7, 4])
tensor2 = torch.tensor([6, 3, 5])

tensor1 * tensor2 # tensor([12, 21, 20])
torch.mul(tensor1, tensor2) # tensor([12, 21, 20])
```

#### <Dot multiplication(product)>

For example, dot multiplication needs summation after multiplication so the result is `53` as shown below.

- Dot multiplication is the multiplication of 1D tensors(arrays).
- The rule which you must follow to do dot multiplication is the number of the rows of `A` and `B` tensors(arrays) is 1 and the number of the columns must be the same.

```
   <A>         <B>
[a, b, c] x [d, e, f] = ad+be+cf
1 row       1 row
3 columns   3 columns

[2, 7, 4] x [6, 3, 5] = 53
                 (2x6)+(7x3)+(4x5)
  [2, 7, 4]
   x  x  x
  [6, 3, 5]
      ||
 [12, 21, 20]
 12 + 21 + 20
      ||
      53
```

In PyTorch with `@`, [dot()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.dot.html) or [matmul()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html):

```py
import torch

tensor1 = torch.tensor([2, 7, 4])
tensor2 = torch.tensor([6, 3, 5])

tensor1 @ tensor2 # tensor(53)
torch.dot(tensor1, tensor2) # tensor(53)
torch.matmul(tensor1, tensor2) # tensor(53)
```

*Memos:

- `dot()` can multiply 1D tensors(arrays) by dot multiplication.
- `@` or `matmul()` can multiply 1D or more D tensors(arrays) by matrix multiplication.