# experimenting random price movement

Tags: random-walk

## Random price movement

Consider the following:

The price of an apple starts at 1 dollar.
On each day, the price will change -10% or +10%, with equal probability.
You buy this apple on day 1, and sell on day N.
What is your probability of losing money at the end?

Suppose N = 2, then we have 4 possible outcomes with equal probability:

- 0.9 * 0.9 = 0.81
- 0.9 * 1.1 = 0.99
- 1.1 * 0.9 = 0.99
- 1.1 * 1.1 = 1.21

Thus the probability of losing money is 3/4.

Let's run an experiment with different delta values (like 10%) and steps (days).

---

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    for delta in [0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8]:
        steps = list(range(1, 20))
        p_lose = [find_p_lose(n, delta) for n in steps]
        plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3))
        plt.title(f"delta = {delta}")
        plt.xlabel("number of steps (days)")
        plt.ylabel("probability of losing")
        plt.xticks(steps)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.plot(steps, p_lose)
        plt.show()


def find_p_lose(steps, delta):
    outcomes = find_outcomes(steps, delta)
    p_lose = len([x for x in outcomes if x < 1]) / len(outcomes)
    return p_lose


def find_outcomes(steps, delta):
    if steps == 1:
        return [1 - delta, 1 + delta]
    outcomes = []
    for a in [1 - delta, 1 + delta]:
        for b in find_outcomes(steps - 1, delta):
            outcomes.append(a * b)
    return outcomes


print("First let's verify what we have at the beginning (2 steps, delta = 0.1)")
print("Outcomes", find_outcomes(2, 0.1))
print("p(lose)", find_p_lose(2, 0.1))

main()
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### Observations

#### Case 1: delta in [0.01, 0.1]

p(lose) oscillates

- It is always 0.5 for **odd** number of steps.
- You are always more likely to lose money for **even** number of steps,
  with the probability decreasing as number of steps increases, and it follows a nice curve.

#### Case 2: delta in [0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8]

p(lose) increases while oscillating

### Questions

1. We can see that there seems to be a **bifurcation** occurring, what is the value of delta where this
   bifurcation occurs?
2. What are the analytical expressions for the curves that the trends are following in both cases?

Comment: A question worth asking yourself: if you lose $10\%$ one day, do you have to gain exactly $10\%$, more than $10\%$, or less than $10\%$ the next day to be back where you were?

Comment: This is really the same as [your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/642324/).  Researching the lognormal distribution here on CV will disclose many answers, some of which you might find helpful.